# Clear Windows memory in order to benchmark a program

Tags: windows, memory, temperature

Cold start in wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_start

When we start a program for the first time, it takes a long time to load. ("cold start" / "cold launch").

If we exit the program and restart it, it loads quickly because some information stays in memory and does not need to be read from disk again.

---

*Synthetic example (windows xp,7,8,10):*

Chrome.exe cold start take 20 seconds.
Second start is 7 seconds.

How to make chrome.exe start as if it was a "cold start"- 20s each time?

This is to test the effect on start time of adding extensions one by one.

Comment: Users are encouraged to vote on questions that they find helpful or not helpful. Users are not obligated to explain their vote.  You attempting to claim, the users who voted on your question are illiterate, is extremely offense.  I would argue that mutiple people are having trouble understanding your question or at the very least believe the question needs some work.  So I encourage you to take that feedback, "this question does not show  any research effort, it is not clear or not useful", to heart and improve your question.

Comment: I make it as simpe as it could be with example and wiki, but ty for comment. The Q is useful for most systems with 4gb ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/rammap) to empty standby memory.